# Create trigger on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `loteria_loterias` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fecha_ini` datetime NOT NULL,
 `fecha_fin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `ganador` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `coste` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `premium` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `duracion` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ganador` (`ganador`),
 CONSTRAINT `loteria_loterias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ganador`) REFERENCES `tegm_users` (`user_login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Is it posible to create a trigger that fill in 'fecha_fin' with 'fecha_ini + duracion' (duracion is in hours) in every insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `some_name` BEFORE INSERT ON loteria_loterias
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.fecha_fin = NEW.fecha_ini + interval NEW.duracion hour;
END;
| 
delimiter ;
```